# Does it make sense to call finish() in onDestroy()?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to debug an issue with our app. Our app is using a framework (Phonegap) which is essentially doing the following weird thing:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
  super.onDestroy();

  finish();
}
```

This seems wrong to me, but I'm not an expert in android programming. Based on my understanding of the activity lifecycle, `onDestroy` is often invoked as the result of calling `finish()`, but never the other way around.

To clarify, the only reason `onDestroy` is being called in the first place is because it had in fact already been torn down by an earlier call to `finish()`. Is it correct to call `finish()` again in onDestroy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. `finish()` is totally unnecessary in there. The activity is already being torn down.

On the other hand, I don't think this should cause problems. The framework is pretty lenient with `finish()` calls (I used to have two on the same activity and I didn't discover it for months). :)

Going further back, do you suspect another problem you're experiencing might be related to this?

Comment: Yes there is a different problem that I am trying to investigate that may be related to this, but I'm really just trying to understand the issue first. The real issue is hard to explain which is why I'm trying to nibble around the edges.

Comment: @1800INFORMATION Well, you might want to cover your bases, but I would be surprised if this was the culprit. Especially if it's part of PhoneGap.

Comment: Just further information, it seems that this bug is actually fixed in the latest phonegap (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2908) - the issue comment there suggests that is is incorrect behaviour and does cause issues

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, calling `finish()` will trigger a call to `onDestroy()` somewhere down the line, but it is not guaranteed.

Your app process could be terminated between the call to `finish()` and the invocation of `onDestroy()`, or the battery could run out and so on.

Therefore, as is also stated in the documentation, calling `finish()` will generally lead to `onDestroy()`, and you need not be calling it from within `onDestroy()`.

You can also use `isFinishing()` to determine if the Activity is already in the process of finishing.

Answer (score 1):

You can still call `onDestroy()` in the `Activity`, but the way you override the `onDestroy` method will cause an exception `SuperNotCalledException`. That is because you cant destroy Activity without calling its `super.onDestroy();`.

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.this.onDestroy();//calling the onDestroy()
        }
    });
```

**problem:**

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
  finish(); //will finish but will catch an exception "SuperNotCalledException"
}
```

@matiash

the way I did it

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("I am called", "I am called");
    finish();

}
```

The fact that this implementation will work but only when you add the `super.onDestroy();`

Comment: It is actually calling `super.onDestroy()`, I just edited that out to simplify my code example

Comment: @1800INFORMATION then that will work when you call finish(), but it is not the right way to finish() an activity you need to at least call it outside the ondestroy.

Comment: Maybe it's not completely clear from my original question, but it's not my code above, it is code in the PhoneGap library that is doing it. I call `finish()` from outside the ondestroy which correctly and completely tears down the activity, but then the `onDestroy` in the PhoneGap library is causing `finish()` to be called again

Comment: @1800INFORMATION then nothing to worry, so when onDestroy is first called then it will release all the memory and when it is called again by the finish() inside the ondestroy, there is nothing in the memory so there is nothing to release, the second call ondestroy to is totally useless.

Comment: The problem is the the second call to `finish()` is causing an unexpected behaviour that is frankly hard to explain but is appearing as an app crash to the users which is why I'm ending up looking into this

Comment: @1800INFORMATION you still override you onDestroy in PhoneGap library and remove the finish().

Comment: If it's in the base class onDestroy(), there is no way to override it, since super.onDestroy() _must_ be called

Comment: Also, it's not true that calling finish() in onDestroy() will call onDestroy() again. If it did, this would cause a stack overflow!

Comment: @matiash just tried just now and it did call it twice.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin You sure? I just re-tested this, just in case, and it did not. Did you call `super.onDestroy()`?

Comment: @matiash look above code what i did, it sure did called twice

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Mighty strange. I copied your code and I'm only seeing one "i am called". :)

Comment: @matiash hmmm.. indeed it is, maybe its because where using different divice.. i guess.

Answer (score 1):

OnDestroy will be called when configuration changes or if the activity is restarting (due to call to  recreate ) , so in some cases it does make sense to call finish().

Comment: This is not correct, `onDestroy()` is called when the activity lifecycle is complete, *as the result of* `finish()` being called

Comment: @1800INFORMATION You're both wrong in different ways. `onDestroy()` can be called by the system without `finish()` being called. `onDestroy()` may be called by the system at any time. It is also the case that `onDestroy()` may be terminated in the middle of running (it is not guaranteed to be executed nor is it guaranteed to return). I would check to see that the `finish()` method being called in `onDestroy()` is in fact an @Override method and not just some local method for cleaning up.

Comment: Oh thanks for that information. `finish()` in this case is definitely an override

Answer (score 0):

onPause() isFinishing(), it would know in onPause if the activity is being finished

Answer (score 0):

You had better clean up *before* `onDestroy()` because there is a very distinct possibility that `onDestroy()` will not be called at all. From the docs for `onDestroy()`:

> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving
>   data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content
>   provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. This method is usually
>   implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an
>   activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things
>   around while the rest of its application is still running. There are
>   situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting
>   process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it
>   should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.

As a side note to the OP and the others posting here, you should all check out the Android lifecycle and read the API docs for the lifecycle callbacks. There's a lot of fuzzy understanding of the lifecycle methods on SO, apparently, because these threads keep popping up.